# OOM when using replay(selectorFoo) but not publish(selectorFoo)

Tags: java, rx-java2, project-reactor

This crashes with OOM:

```
Flowable.range(1, 5000)
        .map(__ -> new byte[1024 * 1024])
        .replay(
          fb ->
            fb.take(1)
              .concatMap(__ -> fb)
          ,1
        )
        .count()
        .toFlowable()
        .blockingSubscribe(c -> System.out.println("args = [" + c + "]"));
```

This is, I think because `replay` is holding to the emissions from upstream, even though I would have thought that the `1` buffer sizse hint would make it not to.... what am I missing?

This doesn't crash:

```
Flowable.range(1, 5000)
        .map(__ -> new byte[1024 * 1024])
        .publish(
          fb ->
            fb.take(1)
              .concatMap(first -> fb.startWith(first))
          ,1
        )
        .count()
        .toFlowable()
        .blockingSubscribe(c -> System.out.println("args = [" + c + "]"));
```

But I am not sure if I am guaranteed that I will get ALL the emissions from upstream like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've investigated this and found the cause of the issue: a bug in `replay` in RxJava 2.

What happens is that `replay` holds references to 2 subscribers, one for `take` and the other for the `concatMap`'s inner consumer in a local variable, thus there is a GC root from the main thread to the defunct `take` still referencing the very first item. Since the bounded replay uses a linked list, this very first item then keeps referencing the newer and newer items via its "next" links and ends up exhausting the memory.

`publish` doesn't keep references to old values thus this is not an issue there.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. In the second example with `publish()` is it possible to lose emission from upstream between the time `take(1)` gets its item and `concatMap` subscribes? I tried to break it in various ways, but I seemed to always get all emissions, but a confirmation from the mastermind behind rxJava2 would be more convincing :). Also, do I file issue on github for this?

Comment: Oh shoot, I've just seen it's already been fixed and merged for next release :). Thanks!

Comment: I will try to answer my question for the `publish()` example. The reactive specifications says that `onNext()` cannot be called concurrently. So an `onNext()` can only be called when previous `onNext()` completed. Since the internal stream of `publish()` doesn't introduce any asynchronicity, this means that the first `onNext()` is called on `take(1)` which then calls `onNext()` on `concatMap()` which will call it's internal function and subscribe to resulting `Flowable`. Only then the next `onNext()` is allowed to be called, so in the given example no emissions can be lost.